# Dataframe Restructuring in a Complete way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id|sub1 |sub2  (header)
1|Rating:2,Grade:C,Semester:3   |Rating:1,Grade:A,Semester:2    
2|Rating:3,Grade:A,Semester:2   |Rating:2,Grade:B,Semester:1
```

I want it to be like this:

```
id|sem|sub|grade|rating
1|3|sub1|C|2
1|2|sub2|A|1
2|2|sub1|A|3
2|1|sub2|B|2
```

I have tried with :

```
df.transpose()
```

Could you suggest a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution with 'melt' and 'extractall':

```
df:
    id                         sub1                         sub2
 0   1  Rating:2,Grade:C,Semester:3  Rating:1,Grade:A,Semester:2
 1   2  Rating:3,Grade:A,Semester:2  Rating:2,Grade:B,Semester:1


df= df.melt(id_vars="id",var_name="sub")                                                                            

   id   sub                        value
0   1  sub1  Rating:2,Grade:C,Semester:3
1   2  sub1  Rating:3,Grade:A,Semester:2
2   1  sub2  Rating:1,Grade:A,Semester:2
3   2  sub2  Rating:2,Grade:B,Semester:1

df2= df["value"].str.extractall(r":(\d+|\w)").unstack()

0      
match  0  1  2
0      2  C  3
1      3  A  2
2      1  A  2
3      2  B  1

df2.columns=["rating","grade","sem"] 

dfrslt= pd.concat([df.drop(columns="value"),df2],axis=1) \
        .reindex(["id","sem","sub","grade","rating"],axis=1) \
        .sort_values("id")

 dfrslt:                                                                                                            

   id sem   sub grade rating
0   1   3  sub1     C      2
2   1   2  sub2     A      1
1   2   2  sub1     A      3
3   2   1  sub2     B      2
```

Answer (score 1):

we can leverage a little regex and assignments

```
pat = (r'Rating:(\d{1})\W+Grade:(\w{1})\W+Semester:(\d{1})')

df.set_index('id',inplace=True)

a = df.sub1.str.extract(pat)
b = df['sub2  (header)'].str.extract(pat)

a['sub'] = 'sub1'
b['sub'] = 'sub2'

df_new = pd.concat([a,b])

df_new.rename(columns={0 : 'Rating', 1 : 'Grade', 2 : 'Semester'},inplace=True)
```

---

```
print(df_new)
     Rating Grade Semester sub
id                          
1       2     C      3  sub1
2       3     A      2  sub1
1       1     A      2  sub2
2       2     B      1  sub2
```

Comment: Thanks!But sub (header) is not a field.I am just telling that the first row is header

Comment: well, I just used the sample data you provided @SampleTest does the above answer your question or is there something missing?

Comment: Actually I have more sub columns like sub1,sub2,...sub20.When I try with this including the other ,I am getting an error like "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas"

Comment: probably better to use melt then with regex :) @Sample Test.